# Load SQLite database to fragment

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to load data from my SQLite file to my maps fragment, there is a table mall inside the sqlite file. I got error cannot find table "mall".
please help.

I have file SQLiteHelper.java

This is my MapsFragment code

```
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);

    // membuat DB
    dbHelper = new SQLHelper(this.getActivity());
    try {
        dbHelper.createDataBase();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Gagal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // Query untuk menampilkan semua Mall
    final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mall", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    // tampung nama mall
    ArrayList<String> spinner_list_mall = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Adapter spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_spinner_mall;

    // nama-nama mall dimasukkan ke dalam array
    spinner_list_mall.add("-- Pilih Mall --");
    for (int i=0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++){
        cursor.moveToPosition(i);
        spinner_list_mall.add(cursor.getString(1).toString());
    }

    // masukkan list Mall ke spinner dropdown
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.list_hotel);
    adapter_spinner_mall = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner_list_mall);
    adapter_spinner_mall.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter_spinner_mall);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() != "-- Pilih Mall --"){
                String mall = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mall, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

This is my SQLite java file. I want to load a file sqlite3.

SQLiteHelper.java

```
public class SQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "go-mall.sqlite3";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
  private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.go_mall.mm.go_mall/databases/";
  private Context myContext;

  public SQLHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    myContext = context;
  }

  public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    if(DataBaseisExist()){
        //do nothing - database already exist
        Toast.makeText(myContext, "Database Sudah Ada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase();
            Toast.makeText(myContext, "Database Berhasil Diimport Dari Assets", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
  }

  private boolean DataBaseisExist(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        //database does't exist yet.
    }
    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }
    if(checkDB != null )return true ;else return false;
  }

  private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

  }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: post your `SQLiteHelper.java` code

Comment: i just edit my post. cheit it again.

Comment: Have you tried using `private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "go-mall";` i.e., not using the extesion `.sqlite3` on the DB name? I do this way here and it works.

Comment: just change your `DB_PATH` like `"/data/user/0/com.go_mall.mm.go_mall/databases/"`

Comment: it solved. I just change .sqlite3 to .sqlite extension